# Visual Studio Express — вопрос по первоначальной установке

Tags: c

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так.

Поступил на программиста, пытаюсь написать первую программу на Си. Скачал последнюю Visual Studio Express, активировал её. Создал новый проект «Пустой проект С++», в папке исходных кодов создал файл `one.cpp`. Добавил туда код, выводящий строчку «Hello world». Далее нажимаю <kbd>F7</kbd> — компилируется секунд 5, хотя в вузе на казёной машине это происходило мгновенно. И потом, когда нажимаю <kbd>Ctrl+F5</kbd>, окошко сразу же закрывается, хотя в вузе нужно было нажать <kbd>↵ Enter</kbd> для закрытия.

Не подскажете, что можно сделать, чтобы было так, как в вузе?

Comment: До утра никак - надо пойти к вам в вуз. Подождите немного.

Comment: скачайте себе лучше линукс в виртуальную машину поставьте его и делайте все ручками, а "ф7" и "сонтрл+ф5" забудьте, они вас ничему не научат. что происходит при компиляции, при линковке и т.д. нужно знать и нужно этому учиться, а кнопки в ide вы успеете научиться нажимать.

Comment: может вы лучше свой код покажете?

Comment: `... на казёной машине это происходило мгновенно` — может быть, там стоит SSD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <ncurses.h>
int main()
{
    initscr();
    printw("Press Any Key To Exit...");
    getch();
    endwin();
}
```